# How do you open this thing without damaging it?

Tags: repair, duplo

It's a 9008 DUPLO Activity Set from 1986. Looks like this on all the boxes.
[image: backside of box]

[image: underneath box]

[image: pic of entire set (not my pic)]

Comment: Hi Beate and welcome to Bricks.SE! Have you tried pushing in the three tabs on the underside of the brick with a suitably sized flat-head screwdriver while prying the cover with a flat tool? Since the three tabs seem to hold the back plate simultaneously, you might need to depress all three at once, so borrow a pair of hands if possible.

Comment: I haven't! Was afraid it might damage it. Thought there might be some special tools of some sort. But I think I'll try on one of them, and get back to you with the results!

Comment: It's definitely not designed to be opened once assembled, but nonetheless it might be doable. Take it slow and be careful, but also keep in mind that ABS can easily be glued even if it breaks. And if you can manage it, please take photos of the process - so that you can contribute the answer for the benefit of future readers :)

Comment: We tried but wasn't able to pry it open :(